# Converting CSV into GRIB2 data for mapping in Leaflet

Tags: csv, leaflet, grib

### TL;DR: I'm looking for some resources on generating GRIB2 data sets on the fly, ideally using in-house-generated wind data in a CSV format.

We have a bunch of data for a series of localized weather stations monitoring wind information around our city. They report in at ~2-3 minute intervals (far more frequent than standard weather data), and from their reports we have lat, lon, wind speed, and wind direction. Someone went and told the boss about these really slick visualizations, like [this](https://ihcantabria.github.io/Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field/example_VectorFieldAnim_ColorBar.html) that can display wind speed and direction, and it's my job to make it happen.

The above plug-in for Leaflet, [GitHub here](https://github.com/IHCantabria/Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field), as well as several others, all use GRIB2 data, which from my research involves a left/right set of data and an up/down set of data for a series of points plotted out across a region.

The problem I'm having is that I've only found a handful of tools that interact with GRIB2 data, and most seem to decode data *from* the GRIB2 dataset, and only one tool running on Fortran seems to exist that compiles GRIB2 data together.

So, is there any way to generate GRIB2 data on the fly using proprietary data at 2-3 minute intervals?

I've gone through [this resource on NOAA's website](https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/), which is where I found a few tools.

Answer (score 0):

I know how frustrating it can be to work with GRIB and some of the other science/weather related formats. This may not be the best answer, but it might be your only answer as I find these types of questions to only gather dust because of the general lack of knowledge with the formats and tools.

From what I remember, CDO tools (link  [here](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo)) can do some magical things - but I am not that experienced with it. I do use it for converting satellite data to plain text and it's been an absolute lifesaver! So I will explain :

My suggestion was to first convert the CSV to netCDF. I had a link saved for this a long time ago, but never came to really needing it. ([discussion here](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/2/topics/7826)). Essentially, some python code should be able to do the conversion for you. There may be several ways to do this, but I have never looked into it beyond initial research.

Next, you *should* be able to convert .nc to .grib using CDO. I know it can do quite alot. [Here is a discussion regarding this, so it must be able to be done](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/1/topics/2907).

I also see  [at this link](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/workshops/2012/third_party/CDO.html) where someone converts grib **to netcdf**, but you should be able to do it in reverse as well. I just don't know the exact commands. From the link :

> As an example of use of CDO, converting from GRIB to netCDF can be as simple as

```
cdo -f nc copy file.grb file.nc
```

I would suspect its just the reverse but probably something like :

```
cdo -f grb file.nc file.grb
```

Hopefully you can put things together  for it to work without being too hack-y.

Comment: Yeah, I usually get obscure projects thrown my way, so I posted this yesterday as I left the office and expected zero responses this morning. So to have even one is great! I'll take a look, thank you!

Comment: No problem. It does look like someone provided a more staightfoward answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a simple python script using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xarray.html) , [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) and [cfgrib](https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib)

```
import pandas as pd
import cfgrib

data = pd.read_csv('your_csv_data.csv')
xarray_data = data.to_xarray()
cfgrib.to_grib(xarray_data, 'out2.grib')
```

Please note that you have to define grib specifications first before you store as grib data.